# How do I disable the JIT-V messages from appearing in the debugger output?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, appv

Something has changed recently on my machine such that I now see lots of .NET JIT-V messages in my Output window while debugging a .NET application. Here's a sample of the sort of output it now shows which I'd like to suppress.

```
JIT-V : Initialize Thread: 7880 : Non-Virtualized
JIT-V : Initialize Thread: 21936 : Non-Virtualized
JIT-V : Initialize Thread: 6080 : Non-Virtualized
JIT-V : Initialize Thread: 9860 : Non-Virtualized
JIT-V : Enabling Virtualization on ThreadId 23320 
JIT-V : Disabling Virtualization on ThreadId 23320 
JIT-V : Initialize Thread: 13136 : Non-Virtualized
```

Does anyone know where the switch to disable these sorts of messages is? FWIW, I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1. Moving to Update 2 or 3 is not an option right now but I suspect that shouldn't be necessary as these are relatively new messages.

I have googled and searched SO for these messages (and parts of these messages) with no useful hits.

My suspicion is that perhaps Debug tools for Windows or some other utility has enabled a regkey or other .NET system-level setting. 
These are definitely not printed from our application code.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with .NET or VS.  Talk to your IT staff about how to configure App-V to get rid of this.

Answer (score -2):

1. open [procexp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653/)
2. find process: SearchIndexer.exe
3. right click it and suspend it and its child processes
4. enjoy!